# Using Web Performance Tests (Visual Studio) with JSON and a data source

Tags: json, visual-studio-2013, performance-testing

I have an AngularJS/WebAPI app that is a wizard style app where you go step by step and type in some information and in the end you get an answer.

I would like to automate this and use a data source but the problem is every page is passing a giant JSON object back to the server with the parameters changing as the user goes through the app.

So for example one of the parameters entered is a ZIP CODE. But to use the DATA SOURCE concept as demoed I would need to create a CSV file which would be like

, , etc..

And that Body/String Body does not have option to add a data source...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The StringBody fields can contain content parameters. They can be edited via the properties panel of the relevant part of the request in Visual Studio. They can be set to text in the style

```
some text {{ContextParameter1}} more text {{ContextParameter2}} even more text
```

the items with doubled curly braces will be replaced with the named context parameters. The rest is taken from the original string body. Values from the data source are made available as context parameter and so can be included. You may need to set the "Select columns" properties of the data source to "Select all columns" to make all values available, the default is just those that are explicitly bound.

Use this method to parameterise sections of the recorded string bodies.

It is also possible to edit the ".webtest" file, it is just an XML representation of the test. However all the string bodies I have seen are 16-bit values (ie 16 bits per character) that are then base-64 encoded.

Comment: Is there a way to capture a particular value in the RESPONSE to the initial HTTP POST ?  Once I have that CaseId if I could somehow put that in all the future HTTP GETs then that would work great

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set up an extraction rule on the first response. This value will be stored in a context variable for use in subsequent requests.

e.g.
`Request1` with either no variables or data sourced variables
`Response1` from which is extracted `myVariable`

`Request2` utilising `{{myVariable}}` extracted previously
`Response2` extract similar . . .

At each subsequent request, replace the section of the json in the string body with `{{myVariable}}`.